# What default function need to be include in new wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a wordpress theme from scratch. 
I created my own page.php, header.php , footer.php, sinngle.php .

When i install any 3rd party plugin , it does not work but works on any third party themes. 
Do i need to include any predefined wordpress API to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several functions you need to add in your theme to make fullfledged WordPress theme.
First read this thoroughly. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Some important points:

- In `header.php`, there should be `wp_head()` function call just before `</head>`
- In `footer.php`, there should be `wp_footer()` function call just before `</body>`
- You need to use WordPress loop properly. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop
- If you want to register Navigation, Sidebar, etc then it should be done in `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

Display your widget in your theme pages like this:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('header_sidebar') ) : 
endif; ?>
```

You of course can replace the `dynamic_sidebar` above with the actual tag name of the 3rd-party widget you wish to integrate.

If you make your own widgets, register them in your functions.php

http://wpgyan.com/how-to-create-a-widget-area-in-wordpress-theme/

Example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Register Widget Area.
 *
 */
function wpgyan_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Header Sidebar',
        'id' => 'header_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpgyan_widgets_init' );
?>
```